# Check for open Windows application and wait until it is closed?

Tags: c#

I have a pretty simple program where it runs certain steps. Each step should run pragmatically. I am having trouble with a bit of my code. Where I am relying on an application to close (waiting for user to close OUTLOOK ) to execute my next block of code. It launches the first file fine but it reads OUTLOOK as open then it wont work. I wish to make it that when the user closes outlook it will continue and open the next HTML file I have tried to Google for something like wait for exit on this line of code  `Process[] localByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK");`
but I couldnt find anything

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var myProcess = new Process { StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\TestFile1.html") };
    myProcess.Start();

    //Launches the html file 

    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    Process[] localByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK"); 
    //used for detecting whether outlook is open  

    if (localByName.Length == 0)
    {
        //Only runs when outlook is closed by user 
        var myProcess2 = 
            new Process { StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\TESTFILE2.html") };

        myProcess2.Start();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Im not going to work " + localByName.Length);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching for the `Process.WaitForExit()`Method ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/fb4aw7b8(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can use it like:

```
foreach(var process in localByName) {
    if(!process.HasExited()) {
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work as I get an error Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'Process[]' does not contain a definition for 'WaitForExit' and no extension method 'WaitForExit' accepting a first argument of type 'Process[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Cob Maker C:\Users\bnowlan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Cob_Maker2\Cob Maker\Cob Maker\Program.cs 76 Active